# OpenZFS on Windows: less available space than capacity in single disk pool

Tags: windows, zfs

Creating a new pool [by using the instructions from readme](https://github.com/openzfsonwindows/ZFSin/blob/master/README.md#creating-your-first-pool), as follows:

```
zpool create -O casesensitivity=insensitive -O compression=lz4 -O atime=off -o ashift=12 tank PHYSICALDRIVE1
```

I get less available space showing up in file explorer and zpool, than the disk capacity itself: 1.76TiB vs 1.81TiB

zpool list and zfs list -r poolname show the difference:

```
zpool list
NAME   SIZE  ALLOC   FREE  CKPOINT  EXPANDSZ   FRAG    CAP  DEDUP  HEALTH  ALTROOT
tank  1,81T   360K  1,81T        -         -     0%     0%  1.00x  ONLINE  -

zfs list -r tank
NAME   USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
tank   300K  1,76T    96K  /tank
```

I'm not sure of the reason. Is there something that ZFS uses the space for?
Does it ever become available for use, or is it reserved, e.g. for root like on ext4?

Answer (score 0):

Because it is copy on write, even deleting stuff requires using a tiny bit of extra storage in ZFS: until the old data has been marked as free (which requires writing newly-created metadata), you can’t start allocating the space it was using to store new data. A small amount of storage is reserved so that if you completely fill your pool it’s still possible to delete stuff to free up space. If it didn’t do this, you could get wedged, which wouldn’t be fixable unless you added more disks to your pool / made one of the disks larger if you are using virtualized storage.

There are also other small overheads (metadata storage, etc.) but I think most of the holdback you’re seeing is related to the above since it doesn’t look like you’ve written anything into the pool yet.